# Alias for virtual host using Apache2

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I am attempting to set up the LAMP environment for the first time. I normally use Windows and just install XAMPP.

I have followed the instructions on Ubuntu forums and have duplicated the file in sites-available.

Currently I can access my site via localhost, but not via either the ServerName or ServerAlias directive.

Here is the file in sites-avialable:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /home/username/example
    <Directory /home/username/example>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should enter `example.com` to your /etc/hosts file and reload apache. You should also enable the virtual host with `sudo a2ensite`.

So:

- Add `NameVirtualHost *:80` to you apache configuration. I add this in top of default in /etc/apache2/sites-available
- Create a virtual host configuration file say `example` in /etc/apache2/sites-available
- Enable it with `sudo a2ensite example`
- Enter your ServerName to your /etc/hosts mapping it to 127.0.0.1
- Restart/Reload apache2 with `sudo service apache2 restart/reload`

I think that ServerAlias is not that necessary