# Virtual host alias doesnt work but localhost:80 does

Tags: networking, server, apache2, windows-subsystem-for-linux, virtualhost

Im trying to set up virtual hosts via apache2 on WSL2.
I have my webpage working properly by http://localhost:80 but not under http://myalias.local

I have positive response for `ping myalias.local` in ubuntu console

etc/hosts from windows

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost ibexa33v1.local
::1             localhost ibexa33v1.local
```

etc/hosts from ubuntu

```
127.0.0.1   localhost   myalias.local
::1 localhost   myalias.local
```

Ports in ports.conf is added
Conf for vhost is created

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myalias.local
    ServerAlias imyalias.local
    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/myalias/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php
```

I tried:
Restarting apache, mariadb,
Double checked the alias spelling,
[Alias for virtual host using Apache2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36095/alias-for-virtual-host-using-apache2)

Comment: Also its worth mentioning than its good to check if you use proper link.
Using https instead of http may cause similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux-based systems, the `hosts` file works best when every domain is on its own line, even when the IPs are the same. This format will work for you:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   myalias.local

::1 localhost   
::1 myalias.local
```

There is no need to restart any services after making this change.

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thanks!